# How to remove images from Firebase Storage?

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-storage

I'm trying to adapt a React Native project to the new `Firebase` methods. In it I upload images to Storage and they are added to the App interface. I can also remove these images from the interface as shown in the following code:

```
const removeImage = (img) => { // delete an image selected by the user
    Alert.alert(
      "Eliminar imagen",
      "¿Estás seguro de eliminar esta imagen?",
      [
        {
          text: "Cancelar",
          style: "cancel",
        },
        {
          text: "Eliminar",
          onPress: () => {
            const result = filter(
              formik.values.images,
              (image) => image !== img
            )
            formik.setFieldValue("images", result)
          },
        },
      ],
      { cancelable: false }
   

 ) 
  }
```

The problem is that in this way, they are only removed from my App, while the images are still stored in `Firebase`. My idea is that when I remove the images from the frontend, they will also be removed from the `Firebase Storage`.

I have read Firebase documentation, and this would be possible with the deleteObject function

```
const storage = getStorage();

// Create a reference to the file to delete
const desertRef = ref(storage, 'images/desert.jpg');

// Delete the file
deleteObject(desertRef).then(() => {
  // File deleted successfully
}).catch((error) => {
  // Uh-oh, an error occurred!
})
```

I did some test, and I can't get it to work.
I don't know exactly how I should add the [Firebase instructions shown here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/delete-files#delete_a_file).

How should I implement this function in my code to remove images from Storage?

Thank you

```
import { getStorage, ref, deleteObject,  uploadBytes, getDownloadURL } from "firebase/storage"
export function UploadImagesForm(props) {
  const { formik } = props
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false) // status for loading

  // Function in charge of opening the image gallery
  const openGallery = async () => {
    const result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
      mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.All,
      allowsEditing: true,
      aspect: [4, 3],
      quality: 1,
    })

    if (!result.cancelled) {
      // console.log('buscando imagenes')
      setIsLoading(true) // uploading the image
      uploadImage(result.uri)
    }
  }

  // function to upload the images to Firebase
  const uploadImage = async (uri) => {
    const response = await fetch(uri)
    const blob = await response.blob()

    const storage = getStorage()
    const storageRef = ref(storage, `restaurants/${uuid()}`)

    // we go to storage where we want to save the images
    uploadBytes(storageRef, blob).then((snapshot) => {
      // console.log(snapshot)
      updatePhotosRestaurant(snapshot.metadata.fullPath)
    })
  }

  // we take the URL in the previous function and set it in the state of the form
  const updatePhotosRestaurant = async (imagePath) => {
    const storage = getStorage()
    const imageRef = ref(storage, imagePath)


    const imageUrl = await getDownloadURL(imageRef) // get the url

    // code to upload all images without replacing them
    // get the current images and add the new ones with the array
    formik.setFieldValue("images", [...formik.values.images, imageUrl])

    setIsLoading(false)
  }

  const removeImage = (img) => { // delete an image selected by the user
    Alert.alert(
      "Eliminar imagen",
      "¿Estás seguro de eliminar esta imagen?",
      [
        {
          text: "Cancelar",
          style: "cancel",
        },
        {
          text: "Eliminar",
          onPress: () => {
            const result = filter(
              formik.values.images,
              (image) => image !== img
            )
            formik.setFieldValue("images", result)
          },
        },
      ],
      { cancelable: false }
    ) 
  }

  return (

    <>
      <ScrollView
        style={Styles.viewImage}
        horizontal
        showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
      >
        <Icon
          type="material-community"
          name="camera"
          color="#a7a7a7"
          containerStyle={Styles.containerIcon}
          onPress={openGallery}
        />
        {map(formik.values.images, (image) => ( // display the images on the screen
          <Avatar
            key={image}
            source={{ uri: image }}
            containerStyle={Styles.imageStyle}
            onPress={() => removeImage(image)}
          />
        ))}
      </ScrollView>
      <Text style={Styles.error}>{formik.errors.images}</Text>
      <LoadingModal show={isLoading} text="Subiendo la imagen" />
    </>
  )
}
```

Comment: You'll need to: 1) Create a reference to the image that you want to remove from Cloud Storage, 2) Pass that reference to the `deleteObject` API. Which step is giving you problems?

Comment: I don't know how to do that @FrankvanPuffelen  , I don't know the way or the code to use to refer to the image. I don't know how to reference each image. I don't know how to [create the reference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/create-reference#create_a_reference)  , I'm confused

Comment: You already create an image reference here: `const storageRef = ref(storage, `restaurants/${uuid()}`)`. You will need to create a similar reference to the image you want to delete.

Comment: Of course, the problem is there, I don't know how to refer to each of the images. As you can see, I remove them from `removeImage`, but I don't understand how I can remove them from `Firestore Storage` at the same time. I don't know how or where to put the functionality in my file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally figured out where to implement the deleteObject function in my file to make it all work.
You can delete the images from the Application and Firebase Storage at the same time.
I found a React expert who helped me with this.

As the **Firebase** documentation says:

To delete a file, first create a reference to that file.

( `const imageRef = ref(storage, img ))`

Firebase explains it like this:

```
import { getStorage, ref, deleteObject } from "firebase/storage";

const storage = getStorage();

// Create a reference to the file to delete
const desertRef = ref(storage, 'images/desert.jpg');
```

Then call the delete() method, (in my case: deleteObject(imageRef) ), for that reference, which will return either a Promise that resolves, or an error if the Promise is rejected.

```
import { getStorage, ref, deleteObject } from "firebase/storage";

const storage = getStorage();

// Create a reference to the file to delete
const desertRef = ref(storage, 'images/desert.jpg');

// Delete the file
deleteObject(desertRef).then(() => {
  // File deleted successfully
}).catch((error) => {
  // Uh-oh, an error occurred!
});
```

I just hope this can help other users who are in my situation learning Firebase

I show. the complete file so that they do not have the doubts that I had, which was the correct place where I should place the Firebase methods

```
            const storage = getStorage()
            const imageRef = ref(storage, img)
            deleteObject(imageRef).then(() => { // also remove the image from Firebase
              console.log("la imagen se elimino");
            }).catch((error) => {
              console.log("ocurrio un error: ", error)
            })
```

Thanks to @FrankvanPuffelen and @BhavyaKoshiya who tried to help.

```
import { getStorage, ref, uploadBytes, getDownloadURL, deleteObject } from 'firebase/storage'
import { v4 as uuid } from 'uuid'
import { map, filter } from 'lodash'

import { LoadingModal } from '../../Shared/LoadingModal/LoadingModal'
import Styles from './Styles'

export function UploadImagesForm(props) {
  
  const { formik } = props
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false) // status for loading

  // Function in charge of opening the image gallery
  const openGallery = async () => {
    const result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
      mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.All,
      allowsEditing: true,
      aspect: [4, 3],
      quality: 1,
    })

    if (!result.cancelled) {
      // console.log('buscando imagenes')
      setIsLoading(true) // uploading the image
      uploadImage(result.uri)
    }
  }

  // function to upload the images to Firebase
  const uploadImage = async (uri) => {
    const response = await fetch(uri)
    const blob = await response.blob()

    const storage = getStorage()
    const storageRef = ref(storage, `restaurants/${uuid()}`)

    // we go to storage where we want to save the images
    uploadBytes(storageRef, blob).then((snapshot) => {
      // console.log(snapshot)
      updatePhotosRestaurant(snapshot.metadata.fullPath)
    })
  }

  // we take the URL in the previous function and set it in the state of the form
  const updatePhotosRestaurant = async (imagePath) => {
     const storage = getStorage()
    const imageRef = ref(storage, imagePath)


    const imageUrl = await getDownloadURL(imageRef) // get the url

    // code to upload all images without replacing them
    // get the current images and add the new ones with the array
    formik.setFieldValue("images", [...formik.values.images, imageUrl])

    setIsLoading(false)
  }

  const removeImage = (img) => { // delete an image selected by the user
    Alert.alert(
      "Eliminar imagen",
      "¿Estás seguro de eliminar esta imagen?",
      [
        {
          text: "Cancelar",
          style: "cancel",
        },
        {
          text: "Eliminar",
          onPress: async () => {
            const result = filter(
              formik.values.images,
              (image) => image !== img
            )
            formik.setFieldValue("images", result)

             **// THIS IS THE CODE I ADDED FROM FIREBASE**
            const storage = getStorage()
            const imageRef = ref(storage, img)
            deleteObject(imageRef).then(() => { // also remove the image from Firebase
              console.log("la imagen se elimino");
            }).catch((error) => {
              console.log("ocurrio un error: ", error)
            })
             **// END OF THE CODE I ADDED FROM FIREBASE**
          },
        },
      ],
      { cancelable: false }
    )
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Great explanation! If anyone has the ref URLs stored in state already, I added the below to my useImages hook and it worked great.

```
const storage = getStorage(); 
const deleteImg = (refUrl) => { 
    const imageRef = ref(storage, refUrl)
    deleteObject(imageRef)
      .catch((error) => {
          console.log("Failed to delete image: ", error)
      })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
let imageRef = storage.refFromURL(URL);
imageRef.delete()
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @BhavyaKoshiya   , but where exactly should I add this ? Should I remove my removeImage function? I do not know how to do it. I have already read the Firebase documentation, but I don't know how to implement it in my code

Comment: Yes inside your removeImage function and provide url of that image

Comment: This didn't work for me, @Bhavyakoshiya

See how it is achieved with the method proposed by Firebase, which I did not know how to implement.
In this way, it worked perfectly, the images of the App and Firebase are deleted.
Thanks for spend your time on me